# Why cant i activate the 4 buttons to start the recording?

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm developing an audio application and i'm wondering why does my audio recorder does not work. There is not visible error according to eclipse, hence i'm very unclear why my recording button does not work

This is my XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnstart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"
    android:text="Start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnfinish"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnstart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"
    android:text="Finish" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnfinish"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnfinish"
    android:onClick="buttonTapped"
    android:text="Play" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnstop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnstart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnplay"
    android:onClick="buttonTaped"
    android:text="stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sound Class File :

```
 package com.example.testproject;

    import java.io.File;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.view.View;

    public class Sound extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private String OUTPUT_FILE;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audio);

    OUTPUT_FILE=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/audiorecorder.3gpp";

}

public void buttonTapped(View view){

    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.btnstart:

    try {
        beginRecording();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;

    case R.id.btnfinish:

    try {
        stopRecording();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;

    case R.id.btnplay:

    try {
        playRecording();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;

    case R.id.btnstop:

    try {
        stopPlayback();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;
    }       

    }

private void stopPlayback(){

}

private void playRecording() throws Exception{
    ditchMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();

}

private void ditchMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null)
    {
        try{
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopRecording(){

    if(recorder != null)
        recorder.stop();

}

private void beginRecording() throws Exception{

    ditchMediaRecorder();
    File outputFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

    if(outputFile.exists())
        outputFile.delete();

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();

}

private void ditchMediaRecorder() { 
    if(recorder != null)
        recorder.release();
}

  }
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.camera"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testproject.Testproject"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

             <activity
        android:name=".Camera"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont seem to have the proper permissions set up in your manifest

add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

to your manifest file and check.